# Spring Data Elasticsearch force create type for current index

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently I am creating Elasticsearch Repository with Class ProductSearch, by adding @document annotation with only indexName, the type should be empty as i didn't manage to add any type to the indexname. But when i call productSearchRepository.findByName(query), it searches inside the indexName with type = "productsearch", here is a snippet of the code.

```
@Document(indexName = "product")
public class ProductSearch extends Product {
}
```

here is the productSearch repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ProductSearch, Long> {
    @Query("{\"match\": {\"name.en\" : \"?0\"}}")
    List<ProductSearch> findByName(String name);
}
```

and here is the logs from elasticsearch which shows that it adds a type = "productsearch"

```
[2016-10-04 14:03:53,634][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Apache Kid] [product][1] took[112.3micros], took_millis[0], types[productsearch], stats[], search_type[DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJtYXRjaCI6IHsibmFtZS5lbiIgOiAiYWJjIn19"}], extra_source[], 
[2016-10-04 14:03:53,634][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Apache Kid] [product][2] took[243.9micros], took_millis[0], types[productsearch], stats[], search_type[DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJtYXRjaCI6IHsibmFtZS5lbiIgOiAiYWJjIn19"}], extra_source[], 
[2016-10-04 14:03:53,634][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Apache Kid] [product][3] took[154.2micros], took_millis[0], types[productsearch], stats[], search_type[DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJtYXRjaCI6IHsibmFtZS5lbiIgOiAiYWJjIn19"}], extra_source[], 
[2016-10-04 14:03:53,634][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Apache Kid] [product][4] took[161.5micros], took_millis[0], types[productsearch], stats[], search_type[DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":"eyJtYXRjaCI6IHsibmFtZS5lbiIgOiAiYWJjIn19"}], extra_source[],
```

What i need is not to create type for my document.

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: A (mapping) type is always mandatory, you cannot store a document in an index without specifying a mapping type. Besides, those logs show that the following query is being run `{"match": {"name.en" : "abc"}}` (decoded from `query_binary`) and that it is slow (i.e. `index.search.slowlog.query`).

Comment: But isn't there any solution to create repository query like this `/product/_search` not `/product/productsearch/_search`, please explain further what do you mean by the logs being slow ?

Comment: Hi! Did you figured that out?
It seems that spring-es creates a type, but only by name. But I need to explicetly name some of the fields for the type (because sorting does not work, if the type is not yet known, e.g. if no documents have been storted yet)

Answer (score 0):

`productsearch` is simply the name used by Spring Data ES to create the mapping type in your `product` index.

In your case, searching in `/product/_search` or `/product/productsearch/_search` will yield the same results (if you have a single type in the `product` index, which seems to be the case).

`/product/_search` is simply a shortcut for searching in all mapping types present in your `product` index.

You can read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/index-modules-slowlog.html) about how to configure slow logs.